# Google Dataflow - BigQuery import job BigQuery/WriteToBigQuery/NativeWrite failed

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataflow

Large Dataflow job here, about 700 Gb of data getting formatted with a final write to BigQuery.

We're running into an issue on both 2.15.0 and 2.16.0 (Python SDK) where the step appears to fail at the final step when it attempts to create an import job:

`Workflow failed. Causes: S04:xxx to BigQuery/WriteToBigQuery/NativeWrite failed., BigQuery import job "dataflow_job_5111748333716803539" failed., BigQuery creation of import job for table "xxx" in dataset "xxx" in project "xxx" failed., BigQuery execution failed., Unknown error.`

This appears to be the very last step and costs a significant amount of CPU time to get here before finally failing with an Unknown error with no obvious way to fix it. We've tried running with different versions of the SDK as noted above (since it looks like there were some changes in 2.16.0 that were BigQuery related) but we are essentially stuck with a lot of sunk CPU hours without any obvious next steps here.

Any ideas about things we could try to fix the issue would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Would you be able to please locate the failed BigQuery import job in the BigQuery web page? https://console.cloud.google.com/ -> (Menu button in top left) -> BigQuery -> Job History -> Project History. Then search for the dataflow_job_5111748333716803539. See if there is a failed one, and see if there is any reason for its failure.

Additionally, Please see if there is any information in the worker logs. Here are some instructions to find them
https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/logging

Comment: Unfortunately I can't locate the failed job since it looks like it fails attempting to create the import job in the first place (no items match). Additionally we don't see any errors in the logs beyond what was posted above.

Comment: Looks like this is happening to others too: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59077104/dataflow-job-fails-at-bigquery-write-with-backend-errors. As a workaround until a fix/solution is found, theoretically you could manually load the files that Dataflow has written to GCS as part of its pipeline into BigQuery. Would this be feasible?

Comment: Please consider trying to use --experiments=use_beam_bq_sink this may resolve the issue. Otherwise you may need to go through Google Cloud Support to resolve this.

Comment: In order to solve these kind of errors which may be particular to each case, the best way is to open a new case with Google Cloud Platform Support. This way we can troubleshoot the case and try to find the solution.