# Dataflow job fails at BigQuery write with backend errors

Tags: python, google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataflow

I have a job which is failing with several different errors related to the final import into BigQuery.  I've run it 5 times and it fails each time, though the error message sometimes varies.  The job worked fine when I ran it locally against an SQLite database, so I think the problem is on the Google backend.

One error message:

```
**Workflow failed. Causes: S04:write meter_traces_combined to BigQuery/WriteToBigQuery/NativeWrite failed., BigQuery import job "dataflow_job_5111748333716803539" failed., BigQuery creation of import job for table "meter_traces_combined" in dataset "ebce" in project "oeem-ebce-platform" failed., BigQuery execution failed., Unknown error.**
```

Another error message:

```
    raceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/dataflow_worker/batchworker.py", line 649, in do_work
    work_executor.execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/dataflow_worker/executor.py", line 178, in execute
    op.finish()
  File "dataflow_worker/native_operations.py", line 93, in dataflow_worker.native_operations.NativeWriteOperation.finish
  File "dataflow_worker/native_operations.py", line 94, in dataflow_worker.native_operations.NativeWriteOperation.finish
  File "dataflow_worker/native_operations.py", line 95, in dataflow_worker.native_operations.NativeWriteOperation.finish
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/dataflow_worker/nativefileio.py", line 465, in __exit__
    self.file.close()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/apache_beam/io/filesystemio.py", line 217, in close
    self._uploader.finish()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/apache_beam/io/gcp/gcsio.py", line 588, in finish
    raise self._upload_thread.last_error  # pylint: disable=raising-bad-type
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/apache_beam/io/gcp/gcsio.py", line 565, in _start_upload
    self._client.objects.Insert(self._insert_request, upload=self._upload)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/apache_beam/io/gcp/internal/clients/storage/storage_v1_client.py", line 1154, in Insert
    upload=upload, upload_config=upload_config)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/apitools/base/py/base_api.py", line 715, in _RunMethod
    http_request, client=self.client)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/apitools/base/py/transfer.py", line 908, in InitializeUpload
    return self.StreamInChunks()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/apitools/base/py/transfer.py", line 1020, in StreamInChunks
    additional_headers=additional_headers)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/apitools/base/py/transfer.py", line 971, in __StreamMedia
    self.RefreshResumableUploadState()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/apitools/base/py/transfer.py", line 873, in RefreshResumableUploadState
    self.stream.seek(self.progress)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/apache_beam/io/filesystemio.py", line 301, in seek
    offset, whence, self.position, self.last_block_position))
NotImplementedError: offset: 10485760, whence: 0, position: 16777216, last: 8388608
```

And another error message:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/dataflow_worker/batchworker.py", line 649, in do_work
    work_executor.execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/dataflow_worker/executor.py", line 178, in execute
    op.finish()
  File "dataflow_worker/native_operations.py", line 93, in dataflow_worker.native_operations.NativeWriteOperation.finish
  File "dataflow_worker/native_operations.py", line 94, in dataflow_worker.native_operations.NativeWriteOperation.finish
  File "dataflow_worker/native_operations.py", line 95, in dataflow_worker.native_operations.NativeWriteOperation.finish
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/dataflow_worker/nativeavroio.py", line 309, in __exit__
    self._data_file_writer.fo.close()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/apache_beam/io/filesystemio.py", line 217, in close
    self._uploader.finish()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/apache_beam/io/gcp/gcsio.py", line 588, in finish
    raise self._upload_thread.last_error  # pylint: disable=raising-bad-type
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/apache_beam/io/gcp/gcsio.py", line 565, in _start_upload
    self._client.objects.Insert(self._insert_request, upload=self._upload)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/apache_beam/io/gcp/internal/clients/storage/storage_v1_client.py", line 1154, in Insert
    upload=upload, upload_config=upload_config)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/apitools/base/py/base_api.py", line 715, in _RunMethod
    http_request, client=self.client)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/apitools/base/py/transfer.py", line 908, in InitializeUpload
    return self.StreamInChunks()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/apitools/base/py/transfer.py", line 1020, in StreamInChunks
    additional_headers=additional_headers)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/apitools/base/py/transfer.py", line 971, in __StreamMedia
    self.RefreshResumableUploadState()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/apitools/base/py/transfer.py", line 875, in RefreshResumableUploadState
    raise exceptions.HttpError.FromResponse(refresh_response)
apitools.base.py.exceptions.HttpError: HttpError accessing <https://www.googleapis.com/resumable/upload/storage/v1/b/oee-ebce-platform/o?alt=json&name=tmp%2Fetl-ebce-combine-all-traces-20191127-152244.1574868164.604684%2Fdax-tmp-2019-11-27_07_24_36-17060579636924315582-S02-0-e425da41c3fe2598%2Ftmp-e425da41c3fe2d8b-shard--try-33835bf582552bbd-endshard.avro&uploadType=resumable&upload_id=AEnB2UqddXXpTnnRQyxBQuL1ptXExVZ5CrUQ33o2S2UHcVUhesrBq7XFSQ90YBQznRm2Wh3g8g8lG1z5uEQv8fXvqO40z5WrnQ>: response: <{'x-guploader-uploadid': 'AEnB2UqddXXpTnnRQyxBQuL1ptXExVZ5CrUQ33o2S2UHcVUhesrBq7XFSQ90YBQznRm2Wh3g8g8lG1z5uEQv8fXvqO40z5WrnQ', 'vary': 'Origin, X-Origin', 'content-type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8', 'content-length': '177', 'date': 'Wed, 27 Nov 2019 15:30:50 GMT', 'server': 'UploadServer', 'status': '410'}>, content <{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "backendError",
    "message": "Backend Error"
   }
  ],
  "code": 503,
  "message": "Backend Error"
 }
}
```

Any ideas?  Job ID 2019-11-27_09_50_34-1251118406325466877, if anyone at Google is reading this. Thanks.

Comment: Looks very similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59077063/google-dataflow-bigquery-import-job-bigquery-writetobigquery-nativewrite-faile

Comment: Please consider trying to use --experiments=use_beam_bq_sink this may resolve the issue. Otherwise you may need to go through Google Cloud Support to resolve this.

Answer (score 1):

Google Cloud Support here. I have inspected your job and I found two internal issues which might be related to this failure. As suggested by Alex Amato in his comment, I would try to use

`--experiments=use_beam_bq_sink`

Otherwise, I would recommend you to open a ticket on GCP directly because this might take further investigation.

I hope that helps.