# Dataflow job fails with HttpError, NotImplementedError

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow

I'm running a Dataflow job which I think should work, and is failing after 1.5 hrs with what looks like network errors.  It works fine when run against a subset of the data.

The first trouble sign is a whole string of warnings like this:

`Refusing to split <dataflow_worker.shuffle.GroupedShuffleRangeTracker object at 0x7f2bcb629950> at b'\xa4r\xa6\x85\x00\x01': proposed split position is out of range [b'\xa4^E\xd2\x00\x01', b'\xa4r\xa6\x85\x00\x01'). Position of last group processed was b'\xa4r\xa6\x84\x00\x01'.`

Then there are four errors which seem to be about writing CSV files to GCS:

`Error in _start_upload while inserting file gs://(redacted).csv: Traceback (most recent call last): File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/apache_beam/io/gcp/gcsio.py", line 565, in _start_upload self._client.objects.Insert(self._insert_request, upload=self._upload) File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/apache_beam/io/gcp/internal/clients/storage/storage_v1_client.py", line 1156, in Insert upload=upload, upload_config=upload_config) File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/apitools/base/py/base_api.py", line 731, in _RunMethod return self.ProcessHttpResponse(method_config, http_response, request) File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/apitools/base/py/base_api.py", line 737, in ProcessHttpResponse self.__ProcessHttpResponse(method_config, http_response, request)) File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/apitools/base/py/base_api.py", line 604, in __ProcessHttpResponse http_response, method_config=method_config, request=request) apitools.base.py.exceptions.HttpError: HttpError accessing <https://www.googleapis.com/resumable/upload/storage/v1/b/(redacted).csv&uploadType=resumable&upload_id=(redacted)>: response: <{'content-type': 'text/plain; charset=utf-8', 'x-guploader-uploadid': '(redacted)', 'content-length': '0', 'date': 'Wed, 08 Jul 2020 22:17:28 GMT', 'server': 'UploadServer', 'status': '503'}>, content <>`

`Error in _start_upload while inserting file gs://(redacted).csv: Traceback (most recent call last): File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/apache_beam/io/gcp/gcsio.py", line 565, in _start_upload self._client.objects.Insert(self._insert_request, upload=self._upload) File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/apache_beam/io/gcp/internal/clients/storage/storage_v1_client.py", line 1156, in Insert upload=upload, upload_config=upload_config) File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/apitools/base/py/base_api.py", line 715, in _RunMethod http_request, client=self.client) File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/apitools/base/py/transfer.py", line 908, in InitializeUpload return self.StreamInChunks() File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/apitools/base/py/transfer.py", line 1020, in StreamInChunks additional_headers=additional_headers) File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/apitools/base/py/transfer.py", line 971, in __StreamMedia self.RefreshResumableUploadState() File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/apitools/base/py/transfer.py", line 873, in RefreshResumableUploadState self.stream.seek(self.progress) File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/apache_beam/io/filesystemio.py", line 301, in seek offset, whence, self.position, self.last_block_position)) NotImplementedError: offset: 0, whence: 0, position: 411, last: 411`

The Dataflow job ID is 2020-07-07_13_08_31-7649894576933400587 -- if anyone from Google Cloud Support is able to look at this I'd be very grateful.   Thanks very much.

P.S I asked a similar question last year ([Dataflow job fails at BigQuery write with backend errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59077104/dataflow-job-fails-at-bigquery-write-with-backend-errors)), the resolution was to use --experiments=use_beam_bq_sink -- I am already doing this.

Answer (score 0):

You can safely ignore "Refusing to split" errors. This just means that the split position Dataflow service provided probably was received by the worker after that position was already read by the worker. Hence the worker has to ignore the split request.

Error "Error in _start_upload while inserting" seems more problematic and seems to be similar to https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/BEAM-7014. I suspect this to be a rare flake though so I'm not sure if this was the reason for your job failure (the job only fails of the same workitem failed four times).

Can you contact Google Cloud support so that they can look into your job ?

I will mention this in the JIRA.

Comment: Thank you Chamicara.  We don't have a support plan but I'm grateful for your help.